# Accessing bytes beyond most-positive-fixnum in emacs lisp

Tags: file-io, elisp, filesize, emacs24

TL;DR: Can 32bit emacs-lisp byte ranges beyond the first 512 MB of a file?

I like using emacs-lisp for various data processing tasks due to its (obviously) high level of integration with the editor.

When thus writing custom functions I sometimes run into limits imposed by `most-positive-fixnum`. While I can live with and understand the reasons for not being able to load a whole 1GB file into a buffer, the `insert-file-contents[-literally]` interface also doesn't allow accessing chunks of data beyond the first 512 MB of a file, since it requires as argument an integer byte range.

Is there some way to circumvent this limitation? As far as I know currently `insert-file-contents` is the most low-level file reading function available to emacs-lisp, `insert-file-contents-literally` being just a variant of the first configured by setting a couple of variables, i.e. emacs-lisp doesn't seem to provide any low-level `fopen` type file interface.

Curiously at some point (possibly using a self-compiled binary) calling `insert-file-contents-literally` with floating point arguments worked for me, allowing access to high byte ranges, at the cost of the risk of rounding errors. Using the latest precompiled emacs version from ftp.gnu.org (24.3 as of writing) however, doing so yields a `(wrong-type-argument file-offset NUMBER)` error.

Comment: Seems you have to use external commands like `head` and `tail`, see http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/VLF. In that case you could fiddle around with `emacs-calc` arbitrary precision numbers.

Comment: Using external commands sadly introduces platform dependence I want to avoid; I'm using emacs on Windows mostly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this solely in Emacs.  You have to use some external program in some way.  It's a known limitation, I believe it is in the bug tracker already.